# ATI Radeon HD 3200 very slow performance

Tags: ati, performance, radeon, 12.10, fglrx

I used ATI fglrx driver for 12.04 with ATI Radeon HD 3200.
After upgrade to 12.10 - there is no fglrx and the system uses standard opensource ATI driver. The driver is very slow especially on playing movies (including flash movies) and on scrolling web pages.

I attempted to install `fglrx*` packages but fglrx in the version `2:9.000-0ubuntu3`  (Catalyst 1.12.8) does not support HD 3200 anymore.

I attemtped to install http://www2.ati.com/drivers/legacy/12-6/amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.zip which seems to be most recent version supporting HD 3200.
But it fails on kernel module compilation without any meaningful messages in logs.

Moreover, [AMD unofficial wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) states that drivers < 1.12.8 do not support kernel 3.5 and xserver 1.13. See also the comment below.

My exact lspci hardware info:

`01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780 [Radeon HD 3200]`

So the question is: how to diagnose performance issue with open source driver for HD 3200 and tune it to get better performance in everyday usage like movies and page scrolling?

Comment: This is a very general problem with 12.10 Quantal and an entire range of cards, as I discovered. You seem to have a specific problem with kernel module compilation, but even if you get past that, you'll run into a bigger problem. Instructions for compilation and the bigger problem are in my post here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-12-6-unsupported-what-to-do

Comment: @AndrewMao, according to [Unofficial AMD Wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) , there is no possibility to use Catalyst < 12.8 (with HD 3200 support) on 3.5 Kernel and 1.13 xserver which confirms your research.

Comment: I found a workaround: Performance issues resolved by switching from default Ubuntu session (Unity) to Gnome Shell session (provided by ``ubuntu-gnome-remix`` packages). No compiz but Gnome Shell compositing with some extensions provide quite adequate replacement for unity+compiz features. The graphics performance is excellent in this configuration.

Answer (score 3):

As I also have found out (4850 here), you can't via any method install fglrx-legacy on stock ubuntu 12.10, even if you use catalyst 12.6 which supports our cards, because the x server that 12.10 uses (1.13) is not supported by catalyst 12.6 or older.

However, this is somewhat of a solution, that I can confirm works on my machine:
http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html

Just follow that (well, uninstall any fglrx you have installed now first), and you should have a better experience.

I should note, you will be downgrading your x server to version 1.12, and these packages are not supported by ubuntu, but this is the closest to a "solution" as can possibly exist at this time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion - I'd rather prefer to stay on ubuntu-supported xserver to not run into another class of issues.
I still believe that OpenSource driver cannot be so bad comparing to fglrx and it might be possible to finetune it - just don't know how (yet)