# Catalyst 12.8 doesn't support Kernel 3.5, Catalyst 12.9 doesn't support my videocard

Tags: ati, catalyst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10)
>   [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on 12.10 Quantal: fglrx (legacy) 12.6 unsupported, what to do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-legacy-12-6-unsupported-wh)

I know there is a some open source driver. What its status and can I enable it in Ubuntu 12.10?

Anyway I got integrated Radeon HD 4250 (It's a previous generation of AMD chipsets, so I guess it's not so old).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe installing legacy fglrx 12.6 would help. Chceck it out: http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html