# installing ati radeon hd driver on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ati, radeon, gpu-driver

I have a hp Probook 4520s with AMD ATI Radeon Graphic HD 530v graphic card .
 when I installed ubuntu 13.04 it recognized a graphic card named : Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV710
and it's working fine , my question is do I need to install Ati Catalyst Control Center for my graphic card or not stick with ubuntu default setting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte)