# Propertiary driver ATI Mobility radeon HD2600

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have got Ati Mobility radeon ,open source driver and Gallium 0.4 on RV 630. This open source driver is not powerful. I downloaded driver from AMD web page and at the beginning of the installation I received this:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

Comment: What driver did you download?

Comment: HD2600 was never powerful to begin with. You can use 12.04 LTS or some older distro that ships with older Xorg.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are installing the legacy FGLRX driver in to Ubuntu 13.04, that is not possible. They require an older kernel and an older X server version than the one you run in 13.04 by default.

[`There are not easy solutions for that fact.`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-legacy-12-6-unsupported-wh)

Your best choices are:

- Downgrade to 12.04 (supported by the legacy driver);
- keep using the open-source one with 13.04.

You cannot use the latest legacy FGLRX driver with 13.04.