# fglrx issues with AMD Mobility Radeon HD 2600 XT on Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

### The problem

I have a rather old (~2007ish) iMac, which I've recently installed Xubuntu 13.04 (64 bit) on. For various reasons it's important that I'm able to get reasonable 2D graphics acceleration on this machine, and unfortunately `mesa` doesn't quite cut it. I've therefore been battling to install the proprietary AMD drivers, but with no success so far.

According to the output of `lspci | grep VGA`, I seem to have an AMD Mobility Radeon HD 2600 XT/2700. Looking in *Settings Manager > Software & Updates >Additional drivers* I don't see any option to install a proprietary display driver.

### Things I've tried:

**1) Installing `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates` from the normal Raring restricted repository**

In both cases `lightdm` doesn't start at all. `dmesg | tail` gives me:

```
[   21.939526] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <joerg.roedel@amd.com>
[   21.939530] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system`
[   22.078527] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 1873 MBytes.
[   22.078991] <3>[fglrx:firegl_init_device_list] *ERROR* No supported display adapters were found
[   22.078993] <3>[fglrx:firegl_init_module] *ERROR* firegl_init_devices failed
```

Based on the [AMD website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.2&product=2.4.2.3.14&lang=us&rev=13.1&ostype=Linux%20x86_64) and on various [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301973/propertiary-driver-ati-mobility-radeon-hd2600) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-legacy-12-6-unsupported-wh) on this site, it seems that the Radeon HD 2000 - 4000 series of adapters is no longer supported by the mainline Catalyst drivers available directly from AMD, or the `fglrx` packages available from the standard Ubuntu repositories.

**2) Adding [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx), downgrading Xserver to 1.12.4 and installing `fglrx-legacy`**

This time the `lightdm` process seems to start, but the display is totally glitched-out (weird moving colour gradients). I see this in `dmesg | tail`:

```
[   18.562524] fglrx_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[   18.562950] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1264
[   18.563022] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1265
[   18.563091] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1266
[   18.563203] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 48 Enabled
[   19.847271] <6>[fglrx] Gart USWC size:624 M.
[   19.847275] <6>[fglrx] Gart cacheable size:245 M.
[   19.847279] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   19.847281] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fe0b000, size:1f5000
```

**3) Installing the legacy Catalyst drivers [downloaded directly from the AMD website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.2&product=2.4.2.3.14&lang=us&rev=13.1&ostype=Linux%20x86_64)**

During the installation I get a message saying `DKMS part of installation failed. Please refer to /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for details`. The install log says this:

```
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.8.0-27-generic --norootcheck......(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.97.100.7 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.97.100.7 from DKMS
```

It's presumably failing to build because that driver only supports kernel versions up to 3.4, whereas mine is 3.8.0-27.

### What next?

Is there any way I can get proprietary AMD drivers working on Ubuntu with a Radeon HD 2600 XT? I'm open to other options, such as downgrading my version of Ubuntu or switching to a different window manager. Could anyone suggest any combination of Ubuntu and Catalyst versions that are likely to be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to downgrade to (x)buntu 12.04, the most recent release that still used xorg 1.12, which is compatible with Radeon's legacy driver. Here and there were posted [instructions for tricking Catalyst into more recent releases](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/), but I haven't heard a success story in a long time. (Disclosure: My own Radeon graphics haven't gone legacy. Personally I don't have this problem yet. I just have an interest.)

Comment: I was initially under the impression that Xorg > 1.12 was specifically a requirement of Unity (post-12.04) - in fact, that's partly why I went for Xubuntu rather than Ubuntu. The link you posted looks pretty much like what I tried in **2)**, so I'm not that hopeful. Do you happen to know if LXDE and KDE also require  Xorg > 1.12?