# ATI Mobility Radeon HD 450

Tags: 13.04, ati, graphics

I've just instaled Ubuntu 13.04 on vaio with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 450, now I need help with instaling drivers for this graphics

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that this graphic card is a 4XXX series card (because the ATI Mobility Radeon HD 450 doesn't exist), I think that this old answer will help you:

https://askubuntu.com/a/305686/153260

Then, this question is duplicated.

Comment: My mistake, I meant HD 4570 ;-)

Comment: Then, update your post to correct the mistake and see my answer, because I answered for your card after all.