# ATI "Radeon HD 2400 PRO" VIdeo card on Ubuntu 15.04 (x64)

Tags: drivers, ati, video, 15.04, radeon

When using 2 screens it works very slowly. WHY?

I thought I need to update video driver. I go to to official site http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu+x86+64 it says -"Distributions supported: 15.04" but I cannot find the file to load. The latest file seems to be "Proprietary Ubuntu 14.04". Am I missing something?

Second thought was about official Ubuntu site, it says "Free, Open Source driver for many ATI graphics cards" has a support for my card. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

But I cannot find a way to install it. Am I missing something again?

Please, help. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/how-to-download-and-install-the-latest-ati-driver-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thank you. The tutorial you provided is sending me back on  amd.com - same as my first link in the question.

Comment: The thing is, I already tried to download and install "AMD Catalyst™ Driver" file from the official AMD site. I thought if it was fine for 14.02 it should be fine for 15.04, but it was not. It did not work, moreover I've got "stuck in a login loop". To get out of which I needed to invest a lot of time. Now, I don't want to play around with soft that was not designed for 15.04 or at least - tested using vesion 15.04. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HD 2400 is NOT supported by ATI anymore [ProofLink](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-HD-4000%2C-HD-3000%2C-and-HD-2000-Series-LINUX-support.aspx)
The only way is to use open source driver that is already inside your ubuntu.
However you can try to loop your login again using [This tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD?action=show&redirect=BinaryDriverHowto%2FATI) or just leave it alone.

Comment: Thanks. I want to add to your answer that this Video card does work fine with one screen with default Ubuntu drivers but it goes nuts with 2 screens. Apart from this problem, default Ubuntu drivers are fine.