# ATI Radeon XPress 1200 Graphics Card Driver Install Problems

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I've got an ATI Radeon XPress 1200 Graphics Card, and the default driver isn't cutting it. I downloaded the proprietary driver .run file ("ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run") from AMD, and tried to run it with `sudo sh ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run`. Everytime I try and to it I get this error:

```
Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:i686:lib::none:3.8.0-25-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro
```

I don't know what's throwing it, and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that your graphics card is not supported by the driver that you are about to install. To be more precise, AMD [dropped support](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware#Radeon_.28Catalyst_.3C.3D_9.3_.26_Open_Source.29) for older graphics cards in Catalyst v. 9.3, which also requires the use of a Kernel older than v. 2.6.28 and X server older than v. 1.5.

Ubuntu 11.10 is the latest release that has a Kernel and X server old enough for the Catalyst v. 9.3. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 11.10 is [no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), so your only solution is to use the open source driver.

You could also use the [ppa:makson96/fglrx](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) PPA to downgrade your Kernel and X server to older versions and to install the legacy driver. However, please read the release notes from the link as the driver isn't fully compatible with the Unity used in Ubuntu 13.04.

If you want to use the PPA, run these commands from the Terminal to downgrade the Kernel and X server and to install the legacy driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've been trying to figure that out for a while now. :P

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I agree with papukaija's answer but I could be wrong. The clue that sticks out to me as most relevant from the information you have given is this line:

```
default:v2:i686:lib::none:3.8.0-25-generic;
```

Is your computer running a 32 bit architecture? That is what i686 indicates: A 32 bit architecture and it looks like you are trying to run an installer for a 64 bit architecture and the installer expects to see a 64 bit one

My guess is that you either have some software already installed that is the wrong architecture for your hardware or you are trying to install something which is the wrong architecture for your hardware. Without knowing what you are running I cannot say what you should do really. Type

```
 uname -a
```

To find out about your install an go from there.