# 12.04 Radeon HD 4200 crap graphics

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I am stuck with 1024x768.  Display comes up as a laptop.  It's a Philips 17"
I have no composition, 2D and fuzzy lines going up the screen.

I used the software centre to install the ATi X.Org binary driver. Useless!
It loads Catalyst.  If I click on Catalyst Control Centre, I get:

> There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.   It could be caused by the following.
>
> No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
>   Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig.
>
> There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.  It could be caused by the following.
>
> No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
>   Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig.

sudo lshw -c video gives:

```
    *-display UNCLAIMED     
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
    vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
    physical id: 5
    bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
    version: 00
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1100(size=256) memory:f0100000-f010ffff memory:f0000000-f00fffff
```

If I do it in terminal, it says missing dependancies and crashes..

I though I hadn't installed it, but:

> fglrx is already the newest version.
>
> fglrx-amdcccle is already the newest version.
>
> fglrx-amdcccle set to manually installed

doing:sudo aticonfig --initial

> aticonfig: No supported adapters detected

It's driving me mad!

I just want my 1280 back and Docky not complaining about compositing all the time.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your card `(Radeon HD 4200)` is too old for the `fglrx` driver available in the ubuntu repositories to work. 
You can try and install the legacy drivers from the AMD website:
 http://support.amd.com/de-de/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64
**but note that these only work up to linux kernel 3.4.x !**
So if the output of the terminal command `uname -r` shows a number higher than 3.4.x you cannot use that one.
In that case you need to uninstall the `fglrx` and `amdcccle` drivers that you installed by typing
 `sudo apt-get purge fglrx amdcccle` and then install the old open-source drivers again.
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon`

Comment: I've uninstalled using the first line, but the second line comes up:                                                               The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: So I installed the broken package and lost the whole screen.  The monitor Just said "Check cable"  
  Thankfully the terminal still worked and I did:  
  >sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get installinstall -f  
  Now I've got my compositing back, so Docky is happy.  

  Amazon are selling an Asus 210 card for £17 so I've ordered it.  

  But hasn't one of the ideas of linux to be able to work on older machines just gone out the window? (which is nearly what happened to this computer).