# Installation of Display Card Driver : [ATI Radeon HD 4770]

Tags: software-installation, fglrx

How to install my display card driver? Previously, I did the following things:

1. Downloaded the official driver from AMD.com : http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64
2. Now I have this : [image]
3. Did this in a terminal : `chmod +x amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run`
4. Did this in the terminal : `sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run` [image]
5. I got this windows, chose the first option and then click "continue" : [image]
6. And this windwos : [image]

   .log file : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7320170/
7. Now what can I do?

**Thank you for your attention**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Desktop Information
------------------------------------------------------------
OS           : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bits)
Display Card : MSI R4770 Cyclone (ATI Radeon HD 4770)*
CPU          : AMD Athlon II X4 620
------------------------------------------------------------
* "No additional drivers available" in "Additional Driver" page
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the mentioned log file with us

Comment: How to find that file...?

Comment: open your terminal 
in the terminal >>  gedit /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log
copy the content to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ 
and send back the link

Comment: The link here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7320170/

Comment: the log says


fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers. /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.

and checking my system also i can't find this file

Comment: @mohtaw  - so... The installation can't be completed...?

Comment: yes , and it seems the same issue in a previous release  please check this link 

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2090453

Comment: ...=[ unhappy about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte)

Answer (score 2):

Your log suggests that you are missing the `linux-headers-generic` package.

You can install this by either searching the software centre or entering in a terminal

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Should the install continue to fail you may also need to install `build-essential`, `gcc`,`dkms` and `make`.

you can do this in a terminal by typing `sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms gcc make`

Comment: It continues to fail. so how to install gcc and make? Thanks!

Comment: You could again search the software centre, or it would be quicker in a terminal , I have updated my answer to include the command you need

Answer (score 0):

That windows is telling that you may do this prior to launch the .run file:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

But maybe you must do all this:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
exit
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --force
```

After a reboot run:

```
aticonfig
```

Note: ATI drivers are for 32 Bit system (yes, i know it says 64bits but it is really 32 bit, if you are fast enough you can see it install things of i386), they can be installed on 64 Bit system but you need 32bit layer on the 64 bit system... same is also needed for ADB (for Rooting Android)... i took the idea from that... on my previous Ubuntu i had to install ia32-libs to be able to use adb (to root an android device from my linux desktop) ... after upgrading to 14.04 all unity icons, dash, and top bar was shown corrupted... so i need to reinstall ATI drivers... so again install 32 bit support for the 64 bit ubuntu ... etc etc, maybe it also help others!

P.D.: Installing ia32-libs tooks a lot of time, so be very pacient!

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, the older driver doesn't work well with programs and the newer driver doesn't support 5K series so your best option is to stick to the x.org open-source driver, however you may wish to proceed.**

If you have previously installed the driver (maybe Ubuntu preinstalled it for you) then do

sudo amdconfig --initial

sudo amdconfig --uninstall

Then after the uninstall you can try installing the driver and if the log gives the same error, force the installation by typing

sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run -force

I have a shitload (5 years) of Amd-Linux experience going from 4290, 4850, 5850, 5870, 6970. Let me know how it goes!