# Installing AMD HD 4xxx Propriety Drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, 14.04, fglrx

I am very new to Ubuntu, have only been using it for 2 days. I am running 14.04

I experienced a few graphics problems while running Dota 2 (Linux version). Fps was fine but a few weird glitchy marks and lines constantly appeared. I thought to download the propriety drivers from Amd website to fix this.

After running the driver in the terminal it gave me a message about 'one or more tools missing', instructing me to go to `usr/share/ati` for more info.

This is what it says:

> Check if system has the tools required for installation.
>
> fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers. 
>   /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be
>   found on this system.
>
> One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the
>   system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
>   Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without
>   the tools.
>
> Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make
>   your system unstable. Not recommended.

----Does anyone have any idea of what I must do here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Which propreitary driver did you install? Can you provide a link to the page from where you downloaded it? Also did you run the 'driver' or the 'driver installer' from your terminal(i suppose it was the latter)?

Comment: As a new user you should be careful about installing software that doesn't come with Ubuntu. If you want to use AMD drivers the best way to do it is to install them by opening the Software Center, clicking the Edit menu and choosing Software Sources/Additional Drivers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsupporte)

Answer (score 3):

from the error it seems that you need to install the kernels headers. You can do that by installing the `linux-headers-generic` package.

```
(In terminal) sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

However, did you tried installing the proprietary drivers directly from ubuntu instead from the Amd website. For that (I suggest to do that since it would be automatically updated and easier) install the package `fglrx` (or if you want a more recent version use `fglrx-updates`).

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Comment: And if fglrx is already installed. sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx && +update-initramfs -u

Answer (score 0):

I think support for "Legacy" ATI cards have been dropped, Catalyst isn't compatible with stock 14.04 kernel, and there won't be updates.