# Ubuntu on Mac black screen

Tags: 14.04, radeon, mac

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a mid 2010 iMac.

When I don't set the `nomodeset` kernel option I'm getting a black screen. It does actually boot because I can hear the login screen sound. The screen is just black.

If I enable nomodeset I'm not getting 3D acceleration using the open-source radeon drivers.

I'm sure its this one: http://support.apple.com/kb/sp588 (I'm not at work so I can't check it). And I'm also for 75% sure it has the "ATI Radeon HD 4670". I'm at least 100% sure its a 4xxx series.

I'm booting using whatever is Ubuntu's default but I'm sure its not EFI. I'm using rEFInd and I'm sure it says 'legacy OS'. So, not EFI.

Comment: Can you post the model number of the iMac please?

Comment: Thanks, When you get a chance, can you confirm it is the model and let us know which of the two graphics card options yours has been configured with? As well as (if you know) whether you're booting via EFI or MBR style grub?

Comment: Have you tried using the proprietary drivers as yet? Or just the radeon. Most of what I'm finding online suggests booting up with nomodeset, installing the drivers, then rebooting and continuing life without nomodeset.

Comment: @amanthethy the problem is that AMD actually deprecated the drivers for the 4xxx series. The driver package no longer supports 4xxx and its not compatible with the Ubuntu 14.04 kernel. About the open-source radeon drivers. I'm actually using those but when you enable ```nomodeset``` the drivers don't support 3D acceleration.

Comment: Ah ok. Makes sense. Those posts I was finding were almost 4 years old. Though, the radeon docs claims the card should be supported by the opensource driver.. hmm

Comment: @amanthethy I'm sure its supported by the open-source driver as well. I do know its actually using software rendering when ```nomodeset``` is enabled, which (obviously) makes Unity very slow.

Comment: I meant in terms of setting radeon.modeset=1 should enable 3D accel with the opensource drivers. I can't find reason it shouldn't work :s I have found this though, if it helps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-ubuntu-12-04-2-and-higher-fglrx-legacy-unsuppor

Comment: @amanthethy I haven't actually tried that yet. I'll have to try that at work tomorrow then.

Comment: @amanthethy I've tried ```radeon.modeset=1``` it causes a black screen

Comment: It appears I can get it work by plugging in a external monitor and then unplugging it. The internal screen then works (well sometimes but unplugging it a few times causes it to work after a while)

Comment: So, in a nutshell, the driver thinks the external display is the built in and the built in the external? If so, I remember reading a similar bug report a while back. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/597070

Answer (score 0):

Doing some further research, I have discovered that your graphics card no longer has drivers supported by ATI. Legacy downloads are also no longer available. And as such, X11 and the Linux Kernel do not support the legacy drivers, even if you were to get a copy elsewhere. In short, it will not work at all. `nomodeset` is, unfortunately, your best option.

***There is another way however.***

As linked in a comment, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/317056/208574) might be able to help you. It will add a PPA where you can get the legacy driver. However, this is very risky and I do not recommend it at all. You will be downgrading you X11 and your kernel, which may break your entire system. Do not try it unless you really, *really*, **really**, ***really*** need the full ATI card power. Other posts in that thread might be able to help you, but back up your PC and be okay with re-installing from scratch.

<sup>If you do follow that answer, I am not responsible for any harm done to your computer. I have given you plenty of fair warning. Backup before even trying that. And do not blame me. I did not force you to try that.

Reason for Linkage: I do not condone following those steps. Consider it like a safeguard. Only view those instructions if you are okay with having to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.</sup>

---

Finally, the open source driver appears not to work due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/597070). I suggest you try to seek help in that forum and maybe even comment that it isn't working for you.

> [Bug #597070](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/597070) -- **Updated 10/18/2014**
>
> Status: <kbd>Fix-Released 8/15/2013</kbd>
>   Importance: <kbd>Medium</kbd>
>   Assigned: <kbd>No</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I use a mid 2010 27" imac with Ubuntu and everytime (thus far) it has been a real pain to install due to the complicated limbo state of the graphics card support. With lots of 'nomodeset', rescue disk, editing x11 conf etc etc.

fglrx in this case is NOT a good idea, it simply does not work properly with 3d acceleration, neither does fglrx-legacy.

However, the most important thing to do, is make sure you are using the right installer. Use the 'mac alternative'. This (14.04.01) is the FIRST time, I have been able to do the whole installation using the GUI installer and be landed in an OS with properly working drivers with 3d acceleration using a 4xxx card (Mobility Radeon HD 4850 in my case).

So thanks ubuntu ! took a while but great.

Installer I used was : ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

From UK mirror

http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/releases/14.04.1/release/

The actual driver packaged with this is the Community driver as described here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Hope that helps some one ( probably me next time I do it! ).

On the note of EFI and booting :
I use rEFIt, I have not had to change it for 4 years, I just reinstall over my previous linux partition. Your Linux partions should not be EFI, they should be Ext4 or something else, heres a print out of mine in case it helps.

```
bob@bob-iMac:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print

Model: ATA ST31000528ASQ (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      20.5kB  210MB   210MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      210MB   100GB   100GB   hfsx            MAC
 3      100GB   300GB   200GB   ext4
 5      300GB   308GB   8000MB  linux-swap(v1)  swap
 6      308GB   1000GB  692GB   ext4            DATA
```

sda3 here is my main installation eg /

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully installed a dual-booting Ubuntu 15.04 on a Mid 2010 21.5" iMac (model 11,2, with Radeon HD 4670) using rEFInd.  I'd messed around with various permutation of `nomodeset` and friends and in the end removing the official (but misbehaving) ATI drivers was the step that allowed me to go back to a normally-booting, single-screen iMac.  It Just Worked (tm).  The steps, from memory, were:

1. Partition the disk to give Ubuntu some space to install
2. Install rEFInd
3. Burn the standard Ubuntu install DVD (iso -> cdr via Disk Utility.  USB stick wasn't working for me)
4. Plug in an external monitor
5. Reboot and select the Ubuntu DVD to boot from the rEFInd menu
6. Once the Ubuntu desktop appears install it.  I allowed it to auto-partition all free space.
7. Eject, reboot.  Choose Ubuntu in the rEFInd menu.
8. Once you've logged in the first thing to do is to remove the official radeon drivers:

   `% sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`
9. Shutdown
10. Unplug the external monitor
11. Power on.  Hopefully you've now got a functioning Ubuntu installation that will work without a second screen.

Performance-wise it all seems quite nippy for a 5-year-old machine.  Runs Windows 8 in VBox fine, handles Blender fluid sims at a reasonable pace etc. I've not tried gaming yet so can't comment on the 3D etc, but WFM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **use the accellerating radeon drivers**, try the solution I described in the my answer this question: [14.04 gets black screen unless radeon.modeset=0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688388/14-04-gets-black-screen-unless-radeon-modeset-0) **remotely turn on your backlight**.

Actualy it does not seem a problem of the radeon X-driver more that there is a point in the boot-process where someone/-ting switches of the backlight. So my solution does not involve a visible console - if you switch to it from the from the window manager.